# C# Convert tag to link with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text of this kind:

> my text my text bla bla bla splendid, **[{~mykeyword|mylink~}]**, some
>   other text **[{~my keyword 2|mylink2~}]**, bla bla etc...

I d like to replace all part starting with `[{~` and ending with `~}]` by a link, `|` separate the link and the keyword. Keywords can have space.

```
<a href="mylink">mykeyword</a><br>
<a href="mylink2">my keyword 2</a>
```

I build the following function which doesn't match any result:

```
public static string ConvertUrlsToLinks(string msg)
{
     string regex = @"(\[{~(\^\w+( +\w+)*$)\|(^\w+( +\w+)*$)\~}])";
     Regex r = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
     return r.Replace(msg, "<a href=\"$1\">$2</a>");
}
```

I guess it's coming from the regex definition.

UPDATE:
The regex from Biffen in the comment working fine with my function. Thank you!

Working function:

```
public static string ConvertUrlsToLinks(string msg)
{
     string regex = @"\[\{~(.*?)\|(.*?)~\}\]";
     Regex r = new Regex(regex, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
     return r.Replace(msg, "<a href=\"$1\">$2</a>");
}
```

Comment: could you provide the exact input along with the expected output? And consider formatting your question.

Comment: You have a lot of strange stuff in your regex, e.g. `\^`, `^` and `$`. It should probably be something a lot simpler, e.g. `\[\{~(.*?)\|(.*?)~\}\]`.

Comment: Yes that's it Biffen, it's working with this Regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sup>Turning my comment into an answer.</sup>

Use this (much simpler) regex:

```
\[\{~(.*?)\|(.*?)~\}\]
```

It will capture the keyword in group 1 and the link in group 2. The ‘trick’ is to use non-greediness. (And to properly escape special characters.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this RegEx to catch [{~yourtag~}]

```
\[{~.*?~}]
```

[Rubular Test](http://rubular.com/r/jsaKnTXvMl). You will have to modify this a little for .NET.